# Converting an integer to a vector of 0's and single 1

Tags: matlab

I have an array of labels in the form:
[1;3;2;]
I wish to convert this to an array of vectors, where only the i'th element is 1, and the rest are 0's.
So the above would be (assuming 5 lables):
[1 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 1 0 0]
[0 1 0 0 0]

How can this be done, without a 'for' loop?

Comment: This is off-topic for MSE, but `A=[1;3;2]; eye(5)(A,:)`.

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong with just doing it?  Let L be the length of the array.  Dimension A(L,5).  Set all elements of A to zero. Then go through the array, in your example set A(1,1)=1, A(2,3)=1, A(3,2)=1 where the first index just counts from 1 to L and the second is the value in that position.

Comment: I'm looking for a vectorized syntax, that's all. Of-course I can do it with a 'for' loop

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do this in Matlab:

```
maxLabel = 5;
x = [1; 3; 2];
M = zeros(length(x),maxLabel);
idx = sub2ind(size(M), 1:numel(x),x)
M(idx) = 1;
```

---

Or more compact for your specific case:

```
M = zeros(3,5);
M(sub2ind([3 5], 1:3,[1;3;2]))
```